# Unable to use wordpress functions inside api plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a plugin to act as api for some request. The structure of it is as below:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'registerRoute' );

function registerRoute() {
  register_rest_route( 'test/v1/', 'mobile', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => array(new testApi(), $_POST['action']),
    ));
}

class testApi
{
 .......
 public function getProduct()
 {
    $post_id = 123;
    var_dump(wc_get_product( $post_id ));exit;
 }
 .......
}
```

In the code above, `wc_get_product returns boolean(false)`. I tried other wordpress functions to see if they return any value , namely:

`get_post($post_id);`

> null

`wp_get_current_user();`

> and this return the following:

```
object(WP_User)#1772 (7) {
  ["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1773 (0) {
  }
  ["ID"]=>
  int(0)
  ["caps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["cap_key"]=>
  NULL
  ["roles"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["allcaps"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["filter"]=>
  NULL
}
```

So, I did some search online and added this piece of code above my file:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

When I echo ABSPATH , it does give me the path string. Also I can use `$wpdb` object;

I wonder why I cannot get the product object by product id like shown above. The product is a bookable product and it still exist in the database.

Please advise me, what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Product object display used `json_decode();`

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'registerRoute' );

function registerRoute() {
  register_rest_route( 'test/v1/', 'mobile', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => array(new testApi(), $_POST['action']),
    ));
}

class testApi
{

 public function getProduct()
 {


    global $product;
    $_product = wc_get_product('215');

    $response = array(
            "result"=>true,
            "data" => json_decode($_product),
            "message"=>'Single Product'
            );

    return $response;
 }

}
```